# spark streaming -- a single lot will cost 40 seconds

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming project, read data from kafka, one minute a processing batch。

Most of the time he is normal, the general processing time will be about 40 seconds, but occasionally will take 80 seconds。

I see the webUI，Sometimes one executor increase 40 seconds, sometimes all executors increase 40 seconds， I have checked a lot of places, and more did not find the problem, there is no one can give some ideas?

Comment: Let me use my ITelepathic powers to login into your github account and check out the code, then into kafka to observe the data being published and finally into your cluster to correlate that with the execution times.

Comment: Looks like my ITelepathic powers are not working. Could you add the code and a data sample?